# Google Sheet to Calendar integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

can anyone help with my script?

Tried to write GAS script for employee vacation. 1/2 successful with that.

1. It's always importing to default calendar. Even if I write it's ID.
2. Vacations added to calendar, but always shorter for 1 day.

Link to my [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gPwAjYdHy-RionAkr6r1PgpeD91lcyNL965cU-XNdEI/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function createCalendarEvent3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("vacations");


  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process - 2 exempts my header row
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var complete = "Done";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[1]; //Item Name
    var date = new Date(row[3]);  //start date
    var rDate = new Date(row[4]); //end date
    var date2 = new Date(row[5]);  //start date1
    var rDate2 = new Date(row[6]); //end date2
    var date3 = new Date(row[7]);  //start date3
    var rDate3 = new Date(row[8]); //end date3
    var date4 = new Date(row[9]);  //start date4
    var rDate4 = new Date(row[10]); //end date4

      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);

    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(name,date,rDate);
    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(name,date2,rDate2);
    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(name,date3,rDate3);
    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(name,date4,rDate4);

      currentCell.setValue(complete);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'd love to help. But your going to have to focus onto one problem and provide a lot more detail about what you have and what you want.Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: Everything you need for the question should be in your post not in some external link.

Comment: _It's always importing to default calendar. Even if I write it's ID._ There's no indication of you using an ID in the code. I would suggest that it is importing to the "default calendar" because you are using lines like `CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(name,date,rDate);`. You need to set the ID in a variable - something like `var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);` (where "calendarId" is the actual calendar ID) and then use something like `eventCal.createEvent(name,date,rDate);`

Comment: This definition for a calendar ` var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("vacations");` is not correct because it returns an iterator not a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Most probably vacations are added one day earlier because the `timeZone` in your calendar doesn't match the one in the dates you used to create the events. In your Calendar, go to `Settings > Time zone` and check that the specified `timeZone` matches the one in your dates.

(2) [CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getdefaultcalendar) returns your default calendar, so it's normal that the events are added to this calendar. If you want to add the events to another calendar, you have to do this instead:

```js
CalendarApp.getCalendarById("your-calendar-id")
```

(3) There is no need for the following line.  You're not using it anywhere else (in any case, this does not return a Calendar but [an array of Calendars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarsByName(String))):

```js
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("vacations");
```

#### Reference:

- [CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getdefaultcalendar)
- [CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById(String))
- [CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarsbynamename)